# Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified. This is a required option and must be explicitly set to `true` or `false` #31

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, use-state, react-native-draggable-flatlist

I am using React-Native-Draggable-View to add a slider into my app, but every time I touch the slider, the above error pops up. When troubleshooting, it claims to have something to do with animation/animated view, but I do not have an animated view in my code. I went further into the docs, and there is no mention of an animated view being required. I used hooks, and the docs use class format, so I am struggling to determine where/how I implement it. Below is what I have so far.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component }from "react";
import {Alert, Dimensions, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, ActivityIndicator, StatusBar} from "react-native";
import {ListScreen} from './ListScreen
import {CheckScreen} from './CheckScreen'
import Drawer from 'react-native-draggable-view'



function RunningScreen({navigation}) {
...

return(

...


<Drawer
    initialDrawerSize={0.3}
    finalDrawerHeight={0.5}

    //autoDrawerUp={0.5}
    renderContainerView={() => (
      <ListScreen navigation = {navigation} 

      
      />
    )}
    renderDrawerView={() => (
      
      <RunningScreen navigation = {navigation} />
    )}
      renderInitDrawerView={() => (
        <View style = {{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3', height: height*0.01, width: width*0.2, alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <StatusBar hidden={false} />
        </View>
        </View>

  )}

/>
    )
    }

...

export {RunningScreen}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Library "react-native-draggable-view" which doesn't have useNativeDriver true or false So you need to open the library and apply "useNativeDriver: false" in the Animated.timing.

Before :

```
 Animated.timing(position, {
        toValue: endPosition,
        tension: 30,
        friction: 0,
        velocity: velocityY
    }).start();
```

After :

```
 Animated.timing(position, {
        toValue: endPosition,
        tension: 30,
        friction: 0,
        velocity: velocityY,
        useNativeDriver: false
    }).start();
```

Comment: This was helpful, but the consensus I have received was that I should not use this library, as it is not being updated. I did not see a warning on the docs stating that it was not being maintained, so I moved forward with it. I appreciate your insight. Is there another library you'd recommend? I was using React-Native-Reanimated-Bottom-Sheet before, but it was not doing quite what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing this because `react-native-draggable-view` hasn't been updated in 3 years and you're using a newer version of react-native. Specifically, > 0.62 where specifying `useNativeDriver` is required. I'm guessing [this](https://github.com/yaraht17/react-native-draggable-view/blob/master/index.js#L74) is the offending `Animated.timing` call from the library. I would edit that block from `node_modules/react-native-draggable-view/index.js` to be

```
Animated.timing(position, {
  toValue: endPosition,
  tension: 30,
  friction: 0,
  velocity: velocityY,
  useNativeDriver: false,
}).start();
```

and see if the error goes away. If it does then you could patch the package to include that fix. You can patch with [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) or [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/patch) if you're using yarn v2.

Comment: Would you recommend against using this library?

Comment: Yes, I would not use it. Mainly because it doesn't appear to be maintained anymore and you'll likely run into similar issues. The library is using the [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) lifecycle method, which won't be supported in newer versions of React. This means you'd have to get rid of the library to upgraded to the latest version of React. Better to do that now.

Comment: Do you have a library to recommend? I was using React-Native-Reanimated-Bottom-Sheet before, and it was not quite doing what I needed, but it I may have just needed to play around with it more

Comment: Nothing to recommend, no. I would probably use the `Animated` from react-native directly instead of using a library.

Answer (score -1):

```
<Carousel
    layout={'tinder'}
    autoplay
    autoplayTimeout={5000}
    loop
    index={0}
    pageSize={BannerWidth}
>
    {images.map((image, index) => this.renderPage(image, index))}
</Carousel>
```